# How to detect when a new Outlook calendar event is added

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, outlook, office365api

Is it possible to detect when a new event is added to an Outlook calendar using the Office 365 API and/or Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:
Notifications or sync.

Calendar documentation:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/calendar

Notification documentation:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/webhooks

SYNC notifications:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/delta_query_overview

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup notification webhook mentioned at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks

Example code is given at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-sample